# Why disabling chrome images turns off gmail chat?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, chat

I disabled automatic loading of images in chrome (via settings/content settings/Do not show any images).

Then I refreshed my gmail(where I was available on gmail chat earlier) page.
Now gmail chat says this: "Unable to reach Gmail. Please check your internet connection or company's network settings". And no contacts are visible.
But my network is fine and other sites are loading perfectly.

Is this the expected behavior of gmail chat or am I experiencing any other problem?

Comment: You could of course add `mail.google.com` to the exceptions with an `allow` (like [so](http://i.imgur.com/fOGaM34.png)). On another note... how would you know if somebody is online if the browser can't show images (like the green of red bulb)? So yeah, i think this is the "expected behavior" of disabling the images.